# Set Arrows 301F to automatically accept RSA keys?

Tags: usb-debugging

Every time I unplug and replug my phone, it asks me to accept the RSA key for my PC.  It says "always allow from this computer", and I toggle that to on.  Regardless, I'm prompted every time.

Is there any way I can just enable my 301F to always accept any RSA key, or to at least always accept the RSA key from this pc?

Answer (score 0):

Likely you started the ADB the first time as ROOT, and now the device doesn't have the permission to write on $HOME/.android/adbkey
now you have to change the owner of that file *(and everything else in that directory)*
`$ sudo chown <your_username> .android/*`   

 and eventually: 
`$ chmod 777 .android/*`

Comment: Yeah, now I'm just wondering if trying to brute force my sim lock will make the phone brick.